# Laravel 5 migrations - foreign key is giving errors

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a table with a foreign key relationship in Laravel 5 migrations. Initially I created a project with `laravel new myproject` so a users table migration is provided. Below is my migration for questions table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('questions');
    }

}
```

..if I run the migration without the foreign method call, it creates the table without errors. However, if I add the foreign method above, I get lots of errors (see below). I can't see from the documentation where I'm going wrong, I'm also following a laracast video and can't see where I'm going wrong either. Is there something wrong with my migration, or could it be something else?

```
Migration table created successfully.
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'questions_development.#sql-409_1d5' (errno: 150)' in /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:358
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(358): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(606): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), 'alter table `qu...', Array)
#2 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(570): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('alter table `qu...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(359): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('alter table `qu...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php(63): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('alter table `qu...')
#5 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php(169): Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint->build(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar))
#6 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php(112): Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->build(Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint))
#7 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(213): Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->create('questions', Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/qadmin/database/migrations/2015_02_15_033437_create_questions_table.php(28): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('create', Array)
#9 /var/www/qadmin/database/migrations/2015_02_15_033437_create_questions_table.php(28): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::create('questions', Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(135): CreateQuestionsTable->up()
#11 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(111): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runUp('2015_02_15_0334...', 1, false)
#12 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(82): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigrationList(Array, false)
#13 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(73): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run('/var/www/qadmin...', false)
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire()
#15 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(523): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(115): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#17 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(253): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(101): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(874): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(195): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(126): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(91): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /var/www/qadmin/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 {main}

Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'questions_development.#sql-409_1d5' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint questions_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)' in /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:614
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(570): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('alter table `qu...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(359): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('alter table `qu...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php(63): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('alter table `qu...')
#3 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php(169): Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint->build(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar))
#4 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php(112): Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->build(Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint))
#5 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(213): Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder->create('questions', Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/qadmin/database/migrations/2015_02_15_033437_create_questions_table.php(28): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('create', Array)
#7 /var/www/qadmin/database/migrations/2015_02_15_033437_create_questions_table.php(28): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::create('questions', Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(135): CreateQuestionsTable->up()
#9 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(111): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runUp('2015_02_15_0334...', 1, false)
#10 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(82): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runMigrationList(Array, false)
#11 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(73): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run('/var/www/qadmin...', false)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire()
#13 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(523): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(115): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#15 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(253): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(101): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(874): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(195): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(126): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/qadmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(91): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/qadmin/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 {main}
```

Comment: What is the engine of your database that you are running the migrations on ? Foreign keys are not supported in the MYISAM engine so make sure you are using INNODB.

Comment: I'm using a MySQL database

Comment: Yes, I do get that but MYSQL gives you the option to specify an engine for your database. Please re-read my edited first comment.

Comment: The first thing you should show the other code, because exception is for `questions_development` database table and not for `questions` table itself.

Comment: OK. What "other code" do I need to show? Sorry I'm just getting started with Laravel 5.

Comment: @Martyn You should include the migration where you create `questions_development` table

Comment: Actually, I didn't use a migration to create the database, only the tables once I'd created the database in phpmyadmin. Didn't realise Laravel migrations did that (I've previously been using Phinx). Should I try and create the database using migrations instead?

Comment: @Martyn it is fine that you have created the table manually in PHPmyadmin. What you need to do is to show the code for migrations for questions_development table. Because it is the one that causes an error.

Comment: questions_development isn't a table, it's the database name.

Comment: @Martyn Do you have `users` table already? Is it created with migration or manually?

Comment: Users table is created with migrations. It's the migration that's is bundled with 'laravel new myproject'. According to the migrations order, it will create users table before questions table. Shall I post users table migration code also? (Need to wait til I finish work tho)